# Errors for running Mahout example

Tags: java, mahout

I downloaded the examples of latest version for chapter 09 of “Mahout in Action”. I can successfully run several examples, but for three files, NewsKMeansClustering.java, ReutersToSparseVectors.java,  and NewsFuzzyKMeansClusteing.java.  Running these three programs gives similar error messages:

> Aug 3, 2011 2:03:54 PM org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics init
>     INFO: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
>
> Aug 3, 2011 2:03:54 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient configureCommandLineOptions
>      WARNING: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should
>      implement Tool for the same.
>
> Aug 3, 2011 2:03:54 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient configureCommandLineOptions
>      WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or 
>      JobConf#setJar(String).
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/user1/workspaceMahout1/recommender/inputDir
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:55)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
>      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
>      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
>
> at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocuments(DocumentProcessor.java:93)
>      at mia.clustering.ch09.NewsKMeansClustering.main(NewsKMeansClustering.java:54)

For the above messages, I do not quite understand what do those two warnings mean? Moreover, it looks like that “input path” should have been created, how can I create this type of input? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the warnings. The error is that the input directory you have specified does not exist. Does it exist? What is your command line?

Comment: Sean, thanks for the response. I imported these examples into Eclipse, and using "Run as application" to run these programs. I guess I need to set the input somehow, but I don't know how to do it. Would you like to give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: This should be in the book. -Dmapred.input.dir is the input flag. You have set it. It's just not there.

Comment: Currently, under the directory of " workspaceMahout1/recommender", I can only find "pom.xml", "src", and "target". I cannot find anything like "inputDir". I checked the book, it seems that "Dmapred.input.dir" is used in a command line. (page 83). But I cannot figure out how this related to my case? Can you give me more details? Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you are running these things ? with what args, etc? No args?

Comment: What I did is just, under Eclipse, right click that program, and "run as application". I think the problem is that I did not give the input. I guess, my issue is that I did not know how to set the input correctly for a given set of files. Then I can pass this input in that java file.  I am a newbie to both Java and Mahout. Thus, a lot of questions have come up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar mismatch. The MiA files at https://github.com/tdunning/MiA have some cases where a .csv file is left in the same dir as the Java source. For example https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/master/src/main/java/mia/recommender/ch02 ... however via Eclipse, loading it using     DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("intro.csv")); ...doesn't find it.

Adding

```
System.out.println("CWD: "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

...will reveal where Eclipse is looking (in my case, a couple levels up the filetree, but this might vary depending on how exactly you've set things up).